# Valgrind invalid read size of 1 within 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, memory-management, size, valgrind

I am fairly new to both valgrind and C and am having trouble interpreting exactly what is wrong with my code. I get an invalid read size of 1 at line 285 and it says that the address is 0 bytes after a block of 5 is alloc'd. My allocation is as follows:

```
output = malloc(sizeof(char**));
output[0] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*size);
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    output[0][i] = malloc(wordLength);
}
```

and the invalid read size and the surrounding lines are:

```
for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
    printf("%s, ", output[0][j]);
    free(output[0][j]);
}
```

I don't free this data anywhere else in my code so I'm not sure what is wrong. Also, there is actually more than just one 2d array within output but I didn't think it was necessary to go into that since this error seems to be rooted with this specific case.

Comment: Is there only a single invalid read size warning or one for each word in output[0]?

Comment: There is one for each word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are words put into this data structure?  The `%s` directive will read characters until it hits a `\0` null terminator.  So if the word is one character longer the allocated memory block the printf line will read one byte past the end.

Comment: I used strncpy with wordLength as the 3rd parameter so it should only be putting wordLength characters into each block

Comment: Does `wordLength` include the null terminator?  If not then strncopy will result in strings that are not null terminated.  Try forcing null termination before the `printf` by doing `output[0][j][wordLength - 1] = 0` and see if the valgrind read errors go away.

Comment: Yes, I will try that because I used strlen to find wordLength which I don't think includes the null terminator.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue I just had to add a null terminator at the end. Thank you